# How type casting is possible in isabelle

Tags: casting, isabelle, isar

Supose I have the following code in Isabelle:

```
typedecl type1
typedecl type2
typedecl type3

consts 
  A::"type1 set"
  B::"type2 set"
```

When I want to use union operation with A and B as bellow:

```
axiomatization where
 c0: "A ∪ B = {}"
```

Since A and B are sets of different types, I get an error of *clash of types* which makes sense! As a workaround I want to type cast A and B to both become sets of type "type3", so I can apply union operations to them. How this type casting is possible in isabelle in this specific example, and how it is possible in general.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type casts require explicit functions between the types, say,

```
consts cast_A :: "type1 ⇒ type3"
consts cast_B :: "type2 ⇒ type3"
```

Using these functions, you can state your axiom as follows:

```
axiomatization where
 c0: "cast_A ` A ∪ cast_B ` B = {}"
```

Isabelle can also automatically insert such coercion functions, but you have to enable it first:

```
declare
  [[coercion_enabled]]
  [[coercion cast_A, coercion cast_B]]
  [[coercion_map image]]
```

These three declarations do the following

1. Enable the coercion inference algorithm.
2. Declare the functions `cast_A` and `cast_B` as coercion functions, i.e., coercion inference may insert them if needed.
3. Declare the function `image` (written infix as ` ) as a map function for coercions. These map functions allow the inference system to apply coercions to the parameters of type constructors. Here, the declaration allows to coerce sets by applying a coercion function to all its elements.

With these preparations, the axiom can be written as before:

```
axiomatization where
 c0: "A ∪ B = {}"
```

However, coercion insertion is only a means to remove clutter from the input notation. The coercions are explicit in the theorem and your proofs have to deal with them. If you look at the theorem `c0`, you will see the coercions.

Finally a comment on these kinds of embedings. The predefined sum type `type1 + type2` consists exactly of all the elements of type `type1` and those of type `type2` with the cast functions `Inl` and `Inr`, respectively. So, if your type `type3` has no other purpose than being the union of `type1` and `type2`, the sum type might be more convenient to work with.

Also note that your axiom expresses that the sets `A` and `B` are empty.